# Can't see relationship in database diagram entity framework core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on ASP.NET Core application which uses Entity framework core. I am using code first approach to create database model. I am trying the get one-to-many relationship (one user can have multiple products) between following two classes but in database diagram, I can not see that relationship.

```
public class SystemUser : IdentityUser
{
    public SystemUser()
    {
        this.ProductToUser = new HashSet<ProductsToUser>();
    }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PinNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductsToUser> ProductToUser { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsToUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public SystemUser SystemUser { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of database diagram.
[image]

As you can see in diagram it is not showing relationship. But I am getting foreign key constraint in `ProductsToUser` table as shown below

[image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on `ProductsToUsers' table > Generate a script > CREATE To and see the output SQL file. If it contains a ALTER TABLE to add a foreign key constraint, then your Entity model works as expect (it creates the foreign).

Comment: When I remove `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` from `ProductsToUser` table then I can see the relationship in the diagram.

Comment: All right. I wonder if that annotation is really useful if the property is already annoted with `[Key]`?

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary. I did not know that `[key]` already makes column identity.